# Difference between buster-backports or bullseye-backports

Tags: debian, package-management

Which debian buster-backports or bullseye-backports for testing package should be selected when current version is stable buster

we know to upgrade current version below lines should be written in sources.list file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main
```

but it is a bit confusing which debian testing packages should be obtained

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
```

or

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
```

Please clearly explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On debian stable (buster) you need to use buster-backports, backports contain a recompiled packages from debian testing for debian stable, testing doesn't have a backports repository. In other word bullseye-backports will be released when bullseye will be stable.

Comment: just receive from a sloppy instruction page saying: `debian bullseye-backports`